# How to pass data to angularJs to server

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have some in put in my form.

```
<input type="text" name = "alias" placeholder="Start Time" style="width:200px"/><br/>
<button ng-click="new()" name="new" >Add</button>
```

How can I pass input value to server to make new user in mongoDb.

The client controller:

```
 $scope.new = function(){
    //$scope.user.$save({ id: $scope.user._id }, function() {
      // $scope.users = User.query();
      // how can I pass from here
    });
}
```

I can get this value in the server controller.js

```
function json_user_save(id) {
  var self = this;

  // self.model('user').Schema;
  // framework.model('user').Schema;
  var User = MODEL('user').Schema;

  console.log('save ->', id);

  // What is it? https://github.com/totaljs/examples/tree/master/changes
  self.change('user: save, id: ' + id);

  var model = self.body;
  var user = new User({ alias: model.alias, created: new Date() }).save(function(err) {

    if (err)
        self.throw500(err);

    // Read all users
    User.find(self.callback());
  });
}
```

How can I pass value from angularjs to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User $http.post method (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and ng-submit directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Answer (score 1):

An even better solution would be the use the Restangular library on top of Angular.

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#collection-methods